# pulumi config change doesn't reflect on output

Tags: pulumi

I following the [stack tutorial](https://www.pulumi.com/learn/building-with-pulumi/stack-outputs/) and after setting the staging stack config frontentPort to 3002 I can see it when running pulumi config  but when I show the output the port is still 3001:

```
$ pulumi config
KEY              VALUE
backendPort      3000
database         cart
frontendPort     3002
mongoHost        mongodb://mongo:27017
mongoPort        27017
nodeEnvironment  development
protocol         http://
$ pulumi stack output url
Enter your passphrase to unlock config/secrets
http://localhost:3001
```

Comment: Did you run a `pulumi up` ?

Comment: @jaxxstorm yes I ran `pulumi up`